# ScheduledExecutorService - program not ending after one-shot action

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, java-8, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a scheduled task in my program that closes a frame after a given period of time. However, after the task has been executed, the program keeps running as if the `ScheduledExecutorService` was still running on a different thread.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
int delay = 1000;

ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ex.schedule(() -> {

    System.out.println("executed");
    getWindow().closeWindow();
    // ex.shutdown();

}, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Here the task is executed after a 1 second delay, "executed" is printed once, the frame closes, and the program keeps running even after this code. If I uncomment the `ex.shutdownNow();`, the program successfully ends as intended. However, I cannot figure out why this is happening. I also failed to find anything from the rest of the Internet.

**MCVE:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int delay = 1000;

        ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ex.schedule(() -> {

            System.out.println("executed");
            // ex.shutdown();

        }, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

}
```

---

The lambdas might've given it away, but this is indeed Java 8.

Why is the program not stopping after the task has been executed?

Comment: You should call `shutdown()` on an executor after all tasks have been submitted, not `shutdownNow()`. This is as per the [ExecutorSErvice API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah, yes, I know. It's irrelevant, though. Pay no attention to it :) I'll edit it outta there anyhoo~

Comment: But the `shutdown()` call is **not** irrelevant, and your code needs it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it is irrelevant. It's a good point, but it's not what I'm asking. I'm asking why the program wont end **without** calling the `shutdown` method

Comment: But it is extremely relevant. Again, please read the API linked that I've given you to see why. This is the whole answer to your over-all question.

Comment: @RichW the `getWindow` method returns a class that handles a `JFrame` jada jada... It's also irrelevant, though: the MCVE omits that particular line and works the same way.

Comment: Olavi, thanks for your response. The comment I added was based on my misreading of your question, so I deleted it. I think Sotirios has the correct answer, below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ScheduledExecutorService` thread pool returned by `Executors#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` uses non daemon threads. Until you shut down the thread pool, these are still alive awaiting tasks. A JVM does not end while non-daemon threads are alive.

You can use the overloaded `Executors#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(ThreadFactory)` and provide your own `ThreadFactory` implementation which creates daemon threads. Note that this risks the case where your task may not even run because the JVM would exit before the task's scheduled time.

Do as you've discovered and shut it down. Note that you should shut always it down somewhere safe, where the operation can't fail.

Comment: Frustrating... still have to wait 3 minutes before I can accept this

Comment: While you're at it, can you provide an example of *somewhere safer* ?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja That is kind of tricky without knowing the layout of your entire application. I've reworded my answer. I don't know enough about swing (or UI programming in general).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can you provide a simple example assuming the provided MCVE is my entire application? I'm sure I can apply the example to my actual program later.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Your MCVE is fine. I was worried about things like `getWindow().closeWindow();` where either might be `null` or can throw an exception. In such a case, you'd want to have a `finally` block in which to execute the `shutdown`. Again, I don't know about apps with non command line GUIs. You may want to consider shutting down your process with a `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Ah, no need to worry about that then. `System.exit(0)` is out of the question in my case, though, since I have two usecases for this code; the other one should exit after that piece of code, the other one shouldn't. Anyway, thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 4):

[The Java Virtual Machine runs until all threads that are not daemon threads have died](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). And `Executors.defaultThreadFactory()` creates each new thread as a non-daemon thread. However, there is an overload of `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();` which takes a `ThreadFactory` as a parameter, if you care to venture in that direction.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int delay = 1000;

        class DaemonFactory implements ThreadFactory
        {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                return t;
            }
        }

        ThreadFactory tf = new DaemonFactory();
        ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(tf);
        ex.schedule(() -> {
            System.out.println("executed");
        }, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: Note that this risks the case where your task may not even run because the JVM would exit before the task's scheduled time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Fair point. It's not of interest however when the program doesn't do anything outside the program (such as file IO, database connections etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this entirely differently. You state:

> I have a scheduled task in my program that closes a frame after a given period of time.

Why not instead use a Swing Timer for this as this was built to work well with the Swing event thread?

```
new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        someWindow.dispose();        
    }

}).start();
```

Comment: I had actually done this after posting my question. I however decided not to edit my post because I was uniformly interested in the reason why `ScheduledExecutorService` wouldn't let the program end after the task was executed.

Comment: To me it looks much cleaner if you call `setRepeats(false)` on the `Timer` before starting it rather than letting the action `stop` the timer, e.g. `Timer t=new Timer(1000, e->someWindow.dispose()); t.setRepeats(false); t.start();`

Answer (score 1):

You can call shutdown from ScheduledExecutorService as it will wait for thread execution and then finalize thread pool. As you can see in Javadoc: "Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will 
 be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down."

Example:

```
...
scheduledExecutorService.schedule(runnable, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am starting scheduler from onCreate() and stopping it in onDestroy() approach to stop the scheduler service.

```
public MyActivity extends Activity
{
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;
    private int apiThreshold = 10;//seconds


onCreate()
{
    startScheduler();
 }

onDestroy()
{
    if (scheduledFuture != null) 
{ 
 stopScheduler(); 
}
 shutDownService();
  super.onDestroy();
 }

 public void startScheduler() {
        Debug.e(TAG, "inside start scheduler");
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // call method to do your task/perform your repeated task
            }
        }, 4, apiThreshold, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


public void shutDownService()
    {
        if (scheduledExecutorService != null) {
            Log.e(“test,"in shutDown service close if not null");
            scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow(); // shutdown will allow the final iteration to finish
            // executing where shutdownNow() will kill it immediately

            Log.e(“test,"is service shutdown(true/false)=="+scheduledExecutorService.isShutdown());
        }
    }

 }
```